# How to escape special char

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.x, ascii

I got the following code to handle Chinese character problem, or some special character in powerpoint file , because I would like to use the content of the `ppt` as the filename to save.
If it contains some special character, it will throw some exception, so I use the following code to handle it.

It works fine under Python 2.7 , but when I run with Python 3.0 it gives me the following error :

```
    if not (char in '<>:"/\|?*'):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

I Googled the error message but I don't understand how to resolve it. I know the code  `if not (char in '<>:"/\|?*'):` is to convert the character to ASCII code number, right?

Is there any example to fix my problem in Python 3?

```
def rm_invalid_char(self,str):

    final=""
    dosnames=['CON', 'PRN', 'AUX', 'NUL', 'COM1', 'COM2', 'COM3', 'COM4', 'COM5', 'COM6', 'COM7', 'COM8', 'COM9', 'LPT1', 'LPT2', 'LPT3', 'LPT4', 'LPT5', 'LPT6', 'LPT7', 'LPT8', 'LPT9']
    for char in str:
        if not (char in '<>:"/\|?*'):
            if ord(char)>31:
                final+=char
        if final in dosnames:
            #oh dear...
            raise SystemError('final string is a DOS name!')
        elif final.replace('.', '')=='':
            print ('final string is all periods!')
            pass
    return final
```

Comment: Can you modify your code to catch the TypeError exception, `print(char)`, and then see what is making it choke? For some reason your string is being interpreted as an array with an integer.

Comment: when i print the char , it shows 232. i think it choke the string, char-wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an iterable whose first element is an integer (232) to `rm_invalid_char()`. The problem does not lie with this function, but with the caller.

Some debugging is in order: right at the beginning of `rm_invalid_char()`, you should do `print(repr(str))`: you will not see a string, contrary to what is expected by `rm_invalid_char()`. You must fix this until you see the string that you were expecting, by adjusting the code *before* `rm_invalid_char()` is called.

The problem is likely due to how Python 2 and Python 3 handle strings (in Python 2, `str` objects are strings of bytes, while in Python 3, they are strings of characters).

Comment: Since the problem is very likely to happen in the code *that calls the one you posted*, I would need you to post that code in order to give a more specific answer. My answer is more general: with print statements you can often figure out what is going on and find the place in the code where the problem originates from, so that you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: use this

```
re.escape(YourStringHere)
```

From the docs:

> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful
>   if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular
>   expression metacharacters in it.

Comment: i change it to `if not char in re.escape('<>:"/\|?*') :` . it doesn;t work too

Comment: Re.escape escapes te special characters in a string, you use it like re.escape("hello ' world") which escapes the '

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why there is something in "str" that is acting like an integer - something strange is going on with the input.

However, I suspect if you:

- Change the name of your `str` value to something else, e.g. `char_string`
- Right after `for char in char_string` coerce whatever your input is to a string

then the problem you describe will be solved.

You might also consider adding a random bit to the end of your generated file name so you don't have to worry about colliding with the DOS reserved names.